# placeholders take up more height than they should

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image, flutter-card

What can I do to make placeholders the same size as the image? Without placeholders `Card` is the same size as the image, so I think that the problem is with the placeholder

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BTM9.jpg)

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: MasonryGridView.count(
          controller: _scrollController,
          crossAxisCount: columns,
          itemCount: images.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final image = images[index];

            return Card(
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                    placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                    image: image.previewUrl,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    width: image.previewWidth.toDouble(),
                    height: image.previewHeight.toDouble()));
          },
        ),
      ),
      _buildLoadingIndicator(),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

the placeholder should be the same size as the image

Comment: What exactly is the placeholder here? I can't see `Placeholder` widget in the code you shared. Or where is the code for what should be your placeholder? And the image you shared doesn't seem to explain the height problem you are talking of

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

`the placeholder should be the same size as the image`

Your images have different size and they are matched against `fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,`

Depending on what you are trying to achive wrap your placeholder with:

- [FittedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html)
- [SizedBox.expand](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.expand.html)

`FittedBox` allows to align image inside of its container to match the width when you set the `fit: BoxFit.fitWidth`. The height of the image and placeholder may vary.

`SizedBox.expand` will take up the space of a parent - in your case whole card.